# Evince can't establish X11 connection over ssh from remote machine

Tags: ssh, x11, remote, evince

Using `ssh -X  remote_machine -l user` to logon to a remote machine, I can't seem to start `evince`.

```
user@remote_machine:~$ evince
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.

** (evince:2040): WARNING **: Could not open X display
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

This is the only GUI application that has this problem. `nautilus`, `kate`, `gedit` or `firefox` can be run with no issues whatsoever and are displayed on my local machine correctly.

To try and solve this, I already deleted `~/.Xauthority` and reconnected afterwards, which didn't help. I also tried opening a .pdf out of `nautilus` but that led to the same error message. The `DISPLAY` environment variable is set like this:

```
user@remote_machine:~$ env | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
```

Might this be a bug in `evince` itself?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes -X doesn't work, try with -Y.

```
ssh -Y  user@remote_machine
```

Comment: errrrr ... why?

Comment: This doesn't help, unfortunately. It also seems to open up potential security vulnerabilities under some scenarios.